# Arch linux boot goes into black screen on laptop with Intel HD onboard graphics

Tags: arch-linux, video

I am on a [Dell Inspiron 11 3000 series](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/inspiron-11-3162-laptop/fncwh101sb) with an Intel Celeron N3050 processor using integrated Intel HD Graphics (Braswell).The CPU architecture is 64-bit (x86_64). The screen has a 1366 x 768 resolution. The system is UEFI enabled. Fast boot and secure boot are both turned off.

I have recently attempted installing Arch Linux with the systemd bootloader. This is my first time running Arch. There are no other operating systems installed, and I have not installed any graphical environments beyond Xorg. I have installed the `xf86-video-intel` and `xf86-video-vesa` graphics drivers.

After selecting the Arch Linux boot option from systemd, the screen goes black shortly into the boot sequence - generally right after the message `[ OK ] Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage` (sometimes just before/after this).

I have tried specifying UXA as the acceleration method in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` but this did not solve the problem. The kernel parameters `acpi_osi="Linux"`, `i915.modeset=1`, `video=SVIDEO-1:d`, and `video=VGA-1:1280x800` also still resulted in black screens (I also tried `video=VGA-1:1366x768`, thinking I might have to specify my native resolution, but had no luck).

I am able to reach the console if I boot with either `i915.modeset=0` or `nomodeset` specified in the kernel parameters, but this leads to very poor performance when running X. I would like to be able to boot without these options, if possible.

What can I do to try and fix this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you end up finding a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Using `i915.modeset` or `nomodeset` disables KMS (kernel mode setting), disallowing the kernel to set up the graphics display, and in turn making X.org responsible for doing so.

Make sure you have *CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE* enabled (preferably set to Y) in the kernel. If your kernel has *CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC* enabled, then you can check for framebuffer like this: `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE`

## Additional resources

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel#Black_screen
- [What is i915.modeset=1 for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/what-is-i915-modeset-1-for)

Comment: Running your given zcat command returned `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y`, `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY=y`, and `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION=y`.

Comment: Also tried `acpi_osi="Linux"` and `i915.modeset=1` as boot parameters, neither fixed the problem.